# Copying Data with Skipped Columns From Excel and Pasting into DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, excel

I've managed to copy from excel and paste it into a datagridview in C#. But when I hold down ctrl, select columns that aren't adjacent to each other, copy and paste into datagridview - all the columns in between were also pasted. Is there a way around this without actually opening the Workbook?

Current implementation simply retrieves `Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData`, formats that into a string and delimit by tab.

Comment: would be better to see the code you have now. You could solve it by copying each part of selected range using loops and `Areas collection`- is it what you accept? However, I still don't get it- you select before copy which means you have file opened but you are asking about method to copy it without opening? which is your real need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately excel just copies everything not just your selected columns for outside world. You can view what is copied to the clipboard using a clipboard viewer (I've used Free Clipboard Viewer). I've created a worksheet with following

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

and selected and copied columns 2, 4 and 6. clipboard viewer shows me what I've copied not three columns but all columns from 2 to 6 (actually Sheet!C2:C6).

You can always open excel using interop or 3rd party component and get what you need and paste it manually which I had to do for converting a grid to excel like grid. I manually parsed comma separated values and set the cells individually.

Comment: In between these months, I actually had a look at what was inside the clipboard, but wanted verification. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

edokan is right when he says that the middle columns are also copied. Is there a setting in Excel which can prevent that? NO.

However here is the simplest way to do achieve what you want.

Before copying Delete unnecessary columns. Then copy and paste. Once done you have two options

1. Close the Excel file without saving
2. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to undo.

If you want a Code solution then yes there is a possibility. Create a VSTO Add-In. What this Add-In will do is copy the relevant columns to clipboard. Not the same as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>